# HTML pattern matching not working

Tags: html

I have an `<input>` element with pattern validation.

```
<input type="text" id="some" pattern="^[A-Z]{5}$" name="some" maxlength="5" style="text-transform:uppercase" required/>
```

The pattern matching works if a user inputs all uppercase characters but fails if any is lowercase. Why is pattern matching not considering `style="text-transform:uppercase"`?

Comment: I suppose that's because it applies the pattern before the transform. So, what you're doing is pointless. You can't transform anything to uppercase because you can only input uppercase letters. Either accept lowercase and transform them, or accept only uppercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text-transform` is only a visual change, not a data change.

See the following example to debug the `<input>`:

```js
function debug()
{
  let inpItem = document.getElementById('some');
  let inpValue = document.getElementById('some').value;
  
  //alert the actual value on input.
  console.log(inpValue);
  
  //set text-transform to default.
  inpItem.style='text-transform:none';
}
```

```css
input {
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="debug()">Debug</button>
<input type="text" id="some" pattern="^[A-Z]{5}$" name="some" maxlength="5" required/>
```

**How you can only input in uppercase?**

You can use JavaScript to set all input values to the uppercase value.

```js
function debug()
{
  let inpItem = document.getElementById('some');
  let inpValue = document.getElementById('some').value;
  
  //alert the actual value on input.
  console.log(inpValue);
  
  //set text-transform to default.
  inpItem.style='text-transform:none';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="debug()">Debug</button>
<input type="text" id="some" pattern="^[A-Z]{5}$" name="some" maxlength="5" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pattern ignores `text-decoration: uppercase;` because it's only styling and original text is still formatted in the way it was inputted.

You should change your pattern to check both uppercase and lowercase symbols.

`^[A-Za-z]{5}$`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why this is happenning, maybe the pattern is processed before the style is given to the input text, but I see you are trying to create a pattern to accept up to five latin characters(uppercase or lowercase, since you are changing them all to uppercase), so why don't you just add lowercase letters to your pattern?

```
pattern="^[A-Za-z]{5}$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will work only if there are 5 consecutive uppercase letters, you can check it here http://regexr.com